# Android GUI with Fragments and different scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollbar

I am new @Android and trying to build a GUI divided into 3 parts (Two different navigation areas on the left/ second below first) and a content area on the right/middle side).

After googling and reading some FAQs I decided to go with Fragments. So far so good, I build an example with ListFragments for NAV and all works fine..

In next step both navigation fragments should be scrollable and contain buttons or images.

And thats my problem:

I have not found a solution how both NAV areas can be horizontally scrolled and the content area vertically. I tried to implement HorizontalScrollView or ViewPages in one Fragment but that didnt work for me.

Can anybody help me or give me some examples which GUI elements have to be used in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. the main layout holds 2 viewpages and a content fragment. this works...

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the usage of Fragments & ViewPagers in the samples section of the ActioBarSherlock project.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html

Comment: So it is possible to slide horizontally over the buttons in nav areas with ViewPagers in Fragments?